# PhoneGap and HTML5/CSS frameworks

Tags: css, cordova, cross-browser, kendo-ui

My question is about compatibility of the code. If I write my own CSS code and mix it with the one that a framework comes with, is there a chance that it won't render well on all platforms?

Do we face the same problem we have with multiple browsers? If I use PhoneGap, should I write code versions for every browser (webkit, mozilla, opera s.o.)?

I would like to have it rendering well on iOS and Android primarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap uses the native web component provided by the OS, e.g UIWebView. iOS and Android use mobile webkit, but other OS use different, e.g. IE10 for WP8.

So, you have the same problem if you target multiple OSes. There are also slight differences from one version of the OS to another...